# Maybe this inequality $\frac{x^3+y^3}{x^2+y^2}\ge\log{\left(\frac{e^x+e^y}{2}\right)}$

Tags: inequality

Let $x,y>0$ .I conjecture
$$\dfrac{x^3+y^3}{x^2+y^2}\ge\log{\left(\dfrac{e^x+e^y}{2}\right)}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your conjecture is false.  Define $$f(x,y) = \frac{x^3+y^3}{x^2+y^2}, \quad g(x,y) = \log \frac{e^x+e^y}{2}.$$  We immediately have $$f(x,2x) = \frac{9x}{5},$$ whereas $$g(x,2x) = x + \log(1+e^x) - \log 2 > 2x - \log 2 > 2x-1,$$ since $\log (1+e^x) > \log e^x = x$ for all real $x$. Consequently $g > f$ for sufficiently large $x$, e.g., $2x - 1 > 9x/5$ or $x > 5$.